# Requiring unexisting password

Tags: password, users

When I created my user account I didn't choose a password but now when I try to install an app it says to authenticate with password, though I know not of a password that I can use. What should I do?

Comment: You need the password you inserted when you **installed** your system. We call that your sudo password and I do not believe you can install Ubuntu without typing a password ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. reboot
2. press and hold `Shift` during boot
3. choose 'recovery mode' or something similar
4. you'll enter an interactive shell
5. Bruno Pereira's comment is correct: Make the filesystem writeable by entering `mount -o remount,rw /` at the #-prompt
6. enter `passwd your_username` at the #-prompt
7. set your password
8. type `reboot`
9. return to your desktop and retry whatever you were doing.

Comment: Recovery does not mount your filesystem rw, you need to mount it rw before changing the user's password.

Comment: By the way, if you don't know your username either, you can get a list of names of users on the system by running `ls /home`. (In Sotiris's case, there is probably just one.)